# QML: superscript/subscript text

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, html4

The problem is that QML totally ignores `<sub>` and `<sup>` html tags, that are actually mentioned in official [Supported HTML Subset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/richtext-html-subset.html#id-ed613049-e204-44d2-816d-74bb4b42ea92).
So the following code will display regular "xy" insted of "x<sup>y</sup>":

```
Text {
text: "x<sup>y</sup>"
}
```

Is there any another possible way to display subscript/superscript text?

UPD: this is a known bug for newest Qt Quick versions since Qt 5.0. You can help getting the bug fixed by voting for it [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24621) or [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32948)

Comment: Try adding [`textFormat: Text.RichText`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop). If it works, let me know so I'll expand this to an actual answer.

Comment: @hyde something changed. But it is far from superscript font... now <sub> and <sup> tags just make characters a bit smaller. Thank's anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think I'll test myself, but some random things to try: different fonts, other markup like bold, newest Qt version (if not already), Qt bug reports (file one if there isn't). As final workaround, write custom component which uses `QPainter` on C++ side or Canvas on QML side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems to be a Qt bug, you need a workaround if you want this to work *now*. As it happens, I was inspired to play with [`Canvas` element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) (which is basically HTML5 canvas element, some documentation for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp)). By taking the hard-coded values from QML properties, the snippet below could be easily expanded to a simple configurable special-purpose text element.

```
Canvas {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPaint: {
        var basetext = 'x';
        var suptext = 'y';

        var ctx = this.getContext("2d");

        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        ctx.font = 'bold 20px serif';
        ctx.strokeText(basetext, 20, 30);

        var metrics = ctx.measureText(basetext);
        console.debug('basetext width:', metrics.width);

        ctx.font = 'italic 12px serif';
        ctx.fillText(suptext, 20+metrics.width, 20);
    }
}
```

Note: when playing around with code like this, it pays to pay attention to the console output, for stuff like warnings about invalid font.

Answer (score 16):

I added *textFormat: Text.RichText* to get sub and sup to work properly:

```
Text {
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: "Normal<sub> Subscript</sub> <sup>Superscript</<sup>"
}
```